# Architecture-independent DBM

Tags: database, cpu-architecture, endianness, leveldb, kyotocabinet

I'm trying to replace GDBM in an application with a better key-value storage manager, and one of my objectives is to use the same database file across different architecture platforms. This, in particular, means it should be independent of the endian-ness and whether the architecture is 32-bit or 64-bit.

Does anyone know if either [Tkrzw](https://dbmx.net/tkrzw/) or [LevelDB](https://github.com/google/leveldb) satisfy this? Or any other key-value DBMs?

Answer (score 1):

Since Tkrzw is a new library, I asked the developer on Github, and according to them it is indeed independent ([source](https://github.com/estraier/tkrzw/issues/3#issuecomment-739469365)).

I also asked the authors of LevelDB, and the answer was also positive ([source](https://github.com/google/leveldb/issues/856#issuecomment-739710458))